# Merge two list together, replace null value of list which is null

Tags: java, spring, list, merge, stream

I want merging 2 list with these conditions

```java
List<int> A = {1,1,1,null,null,null,null,null,null};
List<int> B = {null,null,null,2,2,2,null,null,null};
```

The result I want after merging

```java
List<int> C = {1,1,1,2,2,2,null,null,null}
```

where the `null` value in `list A` will replace with a value in `list B`, Also in case there will have a case like `1 , null, 1, null` I try to use it for loop but I cost a lot of performance I want a proper way to do it

```java
for(int i = 0; i <A.size; i++) 
{
   for(int j=0 ;j <B.size; j++)

}
```

Comment: You cannot use a primitive type for the type-argument of `List`. You'll have to use `Integer` instead of `int`.

Comment: From my understanding of the problem you have two lists 'A' and 'B' and you want to merge based on this condition. replace `null` with a non-value if at a particular index either of the lists contains a `non-null` value right? Also the size of both list are equal right?

Comment: Yes that's right i mean both of list size is equal, with null value in list A it will return with value in list B if both of list have null value in this position there will be null, thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2 loops as you wrote it would mean your code runs the inner bit `A * B` times, which you don't want. You want to run it just 'A' times, assuming A and B are equal in size, or `max(A.size(), B.size())` times if not.

```
var out = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
  Integer v = a.get(0);
  if (v == null) v = b.get(0);
  out.add(v);
}
```

Comment: why the break stmnt ?

Comment: brainfart; should have been `continue;` - fixed.

Comment: In my case when in that position if both of array is null i don't know when add each time it run loops is cost more performance or not

Comment: It wouldn't "cost more performance", that's not how performance works. This adds `null` if both items are `null`.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question.

**Case 1**:  If both Lists are of equal size then you can use Java stream API two write a consistent code without any loop.

```java
List<Integer> C = IntStream.range(0, A.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> {
                    Integer a = A.get(i);
                    Integer b = A.get(i);
                    if (a == null && b != null) {
                        return b;
                    } else if (a != null && b == null) {
                        return a;
                    } else {
                        // assuming when both the value are present
                        // you want to return from list A
                        return a;
                    }
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Case 2**: If both lists can be of unequal size.

```java
List<Integer> C = IntStream.range(0, Math.max(A.size(), B.size()))
                .mapToObj(i -> {
                    Integer a = i < A.size() ? A.get(i) : null;
                    Integer b = i < B.size() ? B.get(i) : null;

                    if (a == null && b != null) {
                        return b;
                    } else if (a != null && b == null) {
                        return a;
                    } else {
                        // assuming when both the value are present
                        // you want to return from list A
                        return a;
                    }
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: There does not appear to be any particular reason to use the stream API here, OP started off with for loops, don't refactor/restyle unnecessarily.

Comment: I think with stream api it make you write your code faster, but both of them are equals about speed

Comment: The for loop based version of this is vastly simpler. These code snippets are needlessly complicated, and it's not about the stream part.